# Retrieve a string value from an Object / Class?

Tags: vb.net, string, aspose

```
Dim tc As Cells = newWorksheet.Cells
Dim tccell As Cell
tccell = tc.Find("PT9", Nothing, findOptions)
```

Note: The “tccell” object declared above As “type Cell” contains a string “J1” that I want to retrieve.
Using VS2010 when I inspect “tccell” it contains the following:
{Aspose.Cells.cell [J1; ValueType: IsString; Value: ABCD]}

How can I extract the value “J1” from “tccell”?

If I try to display tccell: 
MsgBox(tccell) -->Argument 'Prompt' cannot be converted to type 'String'.

How can I use the result from the Find Method as shown above?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Cell`](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsnet/Cell+Class) class has [`Row`](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsnet/Row+Property) and [`Column`](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsnet/Row+Property) properties.  If you want those properties in the alphanumeric format, use one of the [CellsHelper](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsnet/CellsHelper+Class) methods to get that:

```
string cellname = CellsHelper.CellIndexToName(row, col)
```

You might also find that the alphanumeric location of the cell already resides in its [`Name`](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsnet/Name+Property) property.

Comment: Thank You, that is exactly what I was looking for.  So it looks like the  CellsHelper method is just an easy way to make both the Row & Col a string in one easy statement.